# How change the contrast of a volume vtk GDCM

Tags: vtk, gdcm

In the [MIPviewer example](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/MIPViewer_8java-example.html) how can i change the contrast of the volume ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have direct access to the code, simply change the value for:

```
  vtkPiecewiseFunction opacityFun = new vtkPiecewiseFunction();
```